# Query over multiple split years

Tags: querystring

I have a list of year from a form field, not in consecutive order. (ES: 2008, 2010, 2012)

I have built an url in this way: `q=&year[]=2008&year[]=2010` to get all the records of years 2008 and 2010.

I can get the array from url, but was unable to build a query by year on the entries section.

There is a way to query over multiple years?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a plugin (PHP) or from a template (Twig)? And are you trying to query a custom date/time field on the entry or by something like postDate?

Comment: From a twig template. And I'm query the oistDate.

Comment: So from Twig, you want to get all entries where a custom Date/Time field called `oistDate` has year values of 2008 or 2010 or 2012?

Comment: No sorry, the field is the publication date of the post postDate